# Upload Image > Resize > Add Filter / Watermark > Download Image

Tags: php, image-processing, image-resizing, watermark

May you please share any resourceful links I could use to achieve my userflow described in the title? I wish to create a facebook cover maker that adds a filter (a picture of a USA Flag) to the uploaded photo. After some research, I believe what I need is a PHP image resizer and watermarker and manipulation tool.

---

This is almost what I desire: http://www.adylevy.com/demo/imgUpload/

- Visit website
- Upload image
- Image appears
- Replace "Rotate" with "Filter XYZ"
- A watermark appears
- Download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for: http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/ 
Here is an alternative too: https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/